# What year was the spell Lumos taught at Hogwarts?

Tags: harry-potter

In the Harry Potter world; what year do they teach Lumos to the students? Is there any in canon examples of what school year the teachers teach the young Wizards and Witches the spell Lumos?

Comment: The linked duplicate states this is taught first year and is evidenced from the in universe book _"The Dark Forces: A Guide to Self-Protection"_ is a course book for first year that teaches the _"Wand-Lighting Charm"_.